# Is Running HVAC Copper Tube Against Roof Deck OK?

Tags: hvac, roofing, copper-tubing

I am in the middle of getting a new roof installed, and a nail ended up being driven through the copper Freon line (pic below). It seems really ill-considered to me for home builders/HVAC installers to run the tubing this way, i.e. not offset/hung down a bit or protected with some thicker steel flashing to prevent nail strikes like this.
HVAC contractor performing the fix says he sees them run like this all the time. Is this generally OK?
Home was built in 1997 (~25 years old), in Texas, USA.

[image: Punctured HVAC Freon line]

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not OK. I have not run down "what *was* applicable code in Texas in 1997", but [IRC M1411.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-14-heating-and-cooling-equipment-and-appliances#IRC2018_Pt05_Ch14_SecM1404) says that:

> refrigeration lines installed within 1.5 inches of the underside of a
> roof deck shall be protected from nails and other fasteners.

Comment: That requirement seems to make complete sense to me!  But it's a shame standard roofing nails aren't sized (lengthed) to be equal to thickness of shingle(s) + thickness of decking to minimize protrusion underneath.  I've stuck myself in the head more than once while in attic and not paying enough attention to where ceiling/decking was w.r.t. my scalp :--(

Comment: @mblatz01 Some shingles are much thicker than others, and sometimes are installed on top of a previous layer of shingles, so the nails are probably sized to be long enough for the worst case. I know what you mean about the pincushion often visible on the underside of sheathing!